# node + ES6 + Promises : error when inserting nested loops

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

The following Promise function runs well when nested loops are not inserted

```
export function addRolesInGroups(groups) {
  // role items setup
  const roleA1 = { _groupId: groups[0]._id, name: 'admin', description: 
  'can RW group, user', users: [], permissions: permissions1 };
  const roleA1 = ...;

  return Role.insertMany([roleA1, roleA2, roleA3, roleB2, roleB3, roleC3, role4 ])
    .then((insertedRoles) => {
      // nested loops removed
      console.log('NO ERROR');
      return groups;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('ERROR IN role insert: %j', e);
      throw e;
    });
}
```

**console.log**

```
NO ERROR
```

BUT when the nested loops are inserted , an error is catched wo any message
what's wrong with my loops ?

```
export function addRolesInGroups(groups) {
  // role items setup
  const roleA1 = ...;

  return Role.insertMany([roleA1, roleA2, roleA3, roleB2, roleB3, roleC3, role4 ])
    .then((insertedRoles) => {
      // nested loops inserted: will update groups with insertedRoles ids
      for (const role of insertedRoles) {
        for (const group of groups) {
          if (group._id === role._groupId.toString()) { group._roles.push(role._id); }
        };
      };
      console.log('NO ERROR');
      return groups;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('ERROR IN role insert: %j', e);
      throw e;
    });
}
```

**console.log**

```
ERROR IN role insert: {}
```

**UPDATED**

console.log

```
insertedRoles [{"__v":0,"_groupId":"5955382175bdef3c5713dd9e","name":"admin","description":"can RW group, user","_id":"5955382175bdef3c5713dda1","rolePermissions":[],"permissions":[{"resourceName":"group","authorizedActions":["read","write"]},{"resourceName":"user","authorizedActions":["read","write"]}],"users":[]},{"__v":0,"_groupId":"5955382175bdef3c5713dd9e","name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","_id":"5955382175bdef3c5713dda2","rolePermissions":[],"permissions":[{"resourceName":"group","authorizedActions":["read"]},{"resourceName":"user","authorizedActions":["read","write"]}],"users":[]},{"__v":0,"_groupId":"5955382175bdef3c5713dd9e","name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","_id":"5955382175bdef3c5713dda3","rolePermissions":[],"permissions":[{"resourceName":"group","authorizedActions":["read"]},{"resourceName":"user","authorizedActions":["read"]}],"users":[]},{"__v":0,"_groupId":"5955382175bdef3c5713dd9f","name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","_id":"5955382175bdef3c5713dda4","rolePermissions":[],"permissions":[{"resourceName":"group","authorizedActions":["read"]},{"resourceName":"user","authorizedActions":["read","write"]}],"users":[]},{"__v":0,"_groupId":"5955382175bdef3c5713dd9f","name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","_id":"5955382175bdef3c5713dda5","rolePermissions":[],"permissions":[{"resourceName":"group","authorizedActions":["read"]},{"resourceName":"user","authorizedActions":["read"]}],"users":[]},{"__v":0,"_groupId":"5955382175bdef3c5713dda0","name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","_id":"5955382175bdef3c5713dda6","rolePermissions":[],"permissions":[{"resourceName":"group","authorizedActions":["read"]},{"resourceName":"user","authorizedActions":["read"]}],"users":[]},{"__v":0,"name":"visitor","description":"no permissions","_id":"5955382175bdef3c5713dda7","rolePermissions":[],"permissions":[],"users":[]}]
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
  const insertedRolesIterable = insertedRoles => !!insertedRoles && typeof insertedRoles[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
  const groupsIterable = groups => !!groups && typeof groups[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
  console.log('insertedRoles is iterable ?', insertedRolesIterable());
  console.log('groups is iterable ?', groupsIterable());
```

Comment: i imagine there's an error in that line inside the loops, use a try catch and throw the error

Comment: you should  check if `insertedRoles` or `groups` is an iterable because `for of ` loop is only use with objects that have an iterable protocol

Comment: Can you give us an example of a `role`?

Comment: I added a role as an example (@Explosion Pills)
I also added the insertedRoles array displayed in the console. ( @Victory) , iinsertedRole is returned by the Role.insertMany() promise 
Iwill check if it's utterable...

Comment: my question was down voted by someone.. at least this 'someone' should add a comment ...

Comment: I added some checking on the 2 arrays returned by mongoose insertMany() and got the confirmation that they area NOT iterable, as suggested by @Victory

Comment: @Victory Pills -  read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols , and copy/paste the paragraph :  Non-well-formed iterables into an answer so I could vote for it ...  you got the answer ...

Comment: @erwin have you fix the issue ?

Comment: yes ...  I am using  nested nsertedRoles.forEach((role) => { ..} which is working fine on these arrays..